# How to sort a nested Collection by its objects modified value?

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I have an object as follows:

```
IDictionary<string, ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, int>>> myDict;
```

What I'd like to do is to sort its inner collections by keys without underscore prefixes they have.

My attemt on doing so is foollows:

```
myDict = myDict.Select(x => x.Value.OrderBy(v => v.Key.Remove(0, v.Key.IndexOf('_')))).ToDictionary();
```

How could I do this?

Comment: Can you show a sample input and the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ToDictionary` requires two parameters - one for the key selector and one for the value selector, so you could do something like:

```
myDict = myDict.ToDictionary(
            kvp => kvp.Key,
            kvp => ICollection<KeyValuePair<s‌​tring, int>>
                        kvp.Value.OrderBy(v => v.Key.Remove(0, v.Key.IndexOf('_')))
                            .ToList()
            );
```

Comment: @D Stanley Thanks! It seems this is what I need. But unfortunately, I am not able to cast it back to the original type.

Comment: @Andeverien I added a call to `ToList` to turn it back into an `ICollection`.

Comment: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Linq.IOrderedEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>>" unable to cast to
"System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>>".

Comment: @D Stanley Now it's

"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>>" 

unable to cast to

"System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<string, System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>>"

Comment: @Andeverien Added an explicit cast.

Comment: @D Stanley Needed also brackets. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using an [OrderedDictionary(TKey, TValue)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx). Using a custom `IComparer(T)` you can order it however you like.

Something like this:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string first, string second)
    {
        return first.Remove(0, first.IndexOf('_'))
            .CompareTo(second.Remove(0, second.IndexOf('_'));
    }
}
```

Obviously I wouldn't suggest doing the string manipulation on each call, but this should at least demonstrate the basic idea. This will ensure that your items are *added* in this way so it should save some processing later :)